# When and where to use NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Could someone explain the use of notify property changed and in which cases should I be using it?

For example:
I have in my silverlight application the domain data source which loads data and the event LoadedData where I set to some lists (List) the content of the entities from the domain context and bind the lists to the girds.

Do I need to use NotyfiPropertyChanged on the Lists?

Thanks,

Comment: IF the data that you bind needed to unrdergo CRUD operations,then you should use

Comment: it notifies that the UI property has changed and it needs to be updated, to understand better http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Convert your list to ObservableCollection and you wont have any problem. Anyways, if you edit a property and you want it relayed to the view, then user the PropertyChanged

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258262/trying-to-understand-inotifypropertychanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the concepts slightly confused here...

There are two relevant notification interfaces for use with XAML Binding technologies.

`INotifyCollectionChanged` - notifies listeners when the collection of items changes (as in add/remove/replace/reorder actions).

`INotifyPropertyChanged` - notifies listeners that the content of an object has changed (as in values have been set and itself and other properties have changed).

In your case, if you want to notify that the contents of the `List` have changed, you need to use an `INotifyCollectionChanged` enabled collection to do that (i.e. not `List` - typically `ObservableCollection`).

If you wanted to notify that an item within the `List` has changed then the object type contained in the `List` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.